# How to return a reference to a value from Hashmap wrappered in Arc and Mutex in Rust?

Tags: rust

I got some trouble to return the reference of the value in a `HashMap<String,String>` which is wrappered by Arc and Mutex for sharing between threads. The code is like this:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc,Mutex};
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Hey{
    a:Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>>
}


impl Hey {
    fn get(&self,key:&String)->&String{
        self.a.lock().unwrap().get(key).unwrap()
    }
}
```

As shown above, the code failed to compile because of `returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`. I know that `lock()` returns MutexGuard which is a local variable. But How could I achieve this approach to get a reference to the value in HashMap. If I can't, what is the motivation of Rust to forbidden this?

Comment: If that return type were allowed to point inside the Mutex's data, there would be nothing stopping other code from locking the mutex and deleting the entry, meaning that the returned reference would point at something that was deallocated.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yeah you are right. If it's allowed, the map might change due to the operation from another thread, and it's UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me explain why rustc thinks that your code is wrong.

1. You can interact with value protected by Mutex only when you have lock on it.
2. Lock handled by RAII guard.

So, I desugar your code:

```rust
fn get(&self,key:&String)->&String{
   let lock = self.a.lock().unwrap();
   let reference = lock.get(key).unwrap();
   drop(lock); // release your lock
   // We return reference to data which doesn't protected by Mutex!
   // Someone can delete item from hashmap and you would read deleted data
   // Use-After-Free is UB so rustc forbid that
   return reference;
}
```

Probably you need to use `Arcs` as values:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Hey{
    a:Arc<RwLock<HashMap<String, Arc<String>>>>
}
fn get(&self,key:&String)->Arc<String>{
    self.a.lock().unwrap().get(key).unwrap().clone()
}
```

P.S.
Also, you can use `Arc<str>` (and I would recommend that), which would save you from extra pointer indirection. It can be built from String: `let arc: Arc<str> = my_string.into();` or `Arc::from(my_string)`

Comment: Nice! assuming read once and forget kind of operation. However the assumption about consistency here is, a thread getting reference (Arc clone of String) to value of hashmap can keep pointing to value that is no more in Hashmap. i.e. another thread can mutate the map and put another Arc in hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR;

Since, you made the design decision of wrapping your data i.e. `HashMap<String, String>` in `Arc<Mutex<..>>` I am assuming you need to share this data across threads/tasks in a thread safe manner. That is the primary use case for this design choice.

So, my suggestion for anyone reading this today isn't a direct answer(returning reference) to this question rather to change the design such that you return an owned data using something like `.to_owned()` method on the result from the `get` function call.

```rust
fn get(&self, key: &String) -> String {
    let lock = self.a.lock().unwrap(); // #1 Returns MutexGuard
    let val = lock.get(key).unwrap();  
    val.to_owned()
}
```

---

#### Long Form

In the original code snipped, there are actually 2 problems at hand, though only 1 is mentioned in the question.

1. cannot return value referencing temporary value
2. returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Let's try to dig deeper into each of these one by one.

#### Problem 1

**cannot return value referencing temporary value**

The temporary value here is referring to `MutexGuard`. The lock method doesn't return us the reference to the HashMap rather a `MutexGuard` wrapped around the `HashMap`. The reason why `.get()` works on MutexGuard is because it implements `DeRef::deref` trait. Essentially, it means that MutexGuard can deref into the value it wraps when needed. This deref happens when we call the `.get()` method.

We can understand the temporary nature of the mutexguard by diving deeper into how the deref method is implemented under the hood.

```rust
fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T
```

This means that `MutexGuard` can only return reference to `HashMap` for as long as it is alive. Notice the elided lifetime `'a`. But since, we don't store the `MutexGuard` into any local variable rather directly dereference it the rust compiler thinks that it gets dropped right after the `get` call.
The lifetime of the `HashMap` will be same as `MutexGuard`. Any result will share the lifetime of the HashMap. Hence, the value/result from `.get()` method gets dropped instantly.

#### Solution 1: Store the MutexGuard locally

If we store the mutexguard in a local variable using the `let` binding. Then the `HashMap` also has the lifetime of the function scope and the reference/result also has the same lifetime.

```rust
let lock = self.a.lock().unwrap(); // storing MutexGuard in local binding
let val = lock.get(key).unwrap(); // val can live as long as lock is alive which is function's lifetime
```

With this issue fixed, there is just one problem left.

#### Problem 2

**returns a value referencing data owned by the current function**

Since, we take the lock in the current function scope, the reference returned from the `get` function will only be alive for as long as the lock is alive. When we return the reference from the function the compiler will start screaming back at us with the error of data ownership is only valid in the current function scope. It makes sense also, since we only asked(indirectly) for the lock to be active in this function scope. It is semantically wrong to expect the reference to be valid outside the scope of this function.

#### Solution 2: Change in approach

The whole idea of using Arc and Mutex is to add the capability to update the data between multiple threads safely. This thread safety is provided by the `Mutex` which enables locking mechanism on the wrapped data, in your case `HashMap`.

As pointed out by @Abhijit-K, It's not a good design to take the reference of any value outside the scope of the lock.
As explained very nicely in the post by @Angelico the lock is dropped within the scope of the function.

##### Case 1: modifying wrapped data

Only fetch the wrapped value where you have to make changes to the data. Basically, take the lock where you want to change the data, do it in the same scope.

Basically, you pass around the cloned `Arc` between functions to start with. That is the power of Arc, it can give you many cloned references pointing to the same data on the heap.

##### Case 2: reading wrapped data

Take a cloned value instead of the reference. Change the approach to return `String` from `&String`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the ARC and move the clone ARC to another thread/task. From the clone you can lock and access it. I suggest use `RwLock` instead of Mutex if there are more accesses than writes.

When you clone ARC you are not cloning the underlying object just the ARC. Also in your case you need to wrap the struct into ARC or change the design, as it is ARC that should be cloned and moved

---

Approach to share the object should be via guard I believe. With RWLock multiple can read map via the guards:

```
use async_std::task;
use std::sync::{Arc,RwLock, RwLockReadGuard, RwLockWriteGuard};
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Hey{
    a:Arc<RwLock<HashMap<String, String>>>
}

impl Hey {      

    pub fn read(&self) -> RwLockReadGuard<'_, HashMap<String, String>> {
        self.a.read().unwrap()
    }

    
    pub fn write(&self) -> RwLockWriteGuard<'_, HashMap<String, String>> {
        self.a.write().unwrap()
    }    
}


fn main() {
    let h = Hey{..Default::default()};

    h.write().insert("k1".to_string(), "v1".to_string());
   
    println!("{:?}", h.read().get("k1"));
    task::block_on(async move {
        println!("{:?}", h.read().get("k1"));
    });

}
```

Comment: I think you miss my words. The compile error is because `lock()` in `Mutex` return a temporary variable whose lifetime belongs to the scope of `get` function. So it cannot return the reference. For now, it's not due to the threads.

Comment: I believe with get fn ref to hashmap and then returning inside ref to string; instead I shared my approach to geturn the guard. That would allow to read concurrently as it is RWlock